# Display resolution only has 1 option 1920x1080

Tags: display-resolution

I'm running xubuntu 16.04.1.  Today I updated an rebooted.  Now I'm stuck in 1920 x 1080.  I'm older and like a lower resolution.  Also I can't seem to change the brightness now.

What do I do?

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080      0.00*
```

Before the update I had other resolutions in arandr.

```
 $ lspci | grep -i vga
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a driver error. Make sure you have the correct Intel drivers.

Check the system logs.

Go here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and install the update tool.

You might want to see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209157/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-for-guest-centos-6-6-h

You might not need to change the resolution- try the following:

Change the system UI scaling and font size from "System Settings>Displays>Scaling for Menu and Title Bars".

If you are using chrome, you can change the UI scaling by going to the chrome.desktop file (usually located in /usr/share/applications) and editing this line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1 %U
```

Change "--force-device-scale-factor=" to a number higher than 1 for large UI.

Comment: Intel, I've updated my question...

Comment: Edited, see updated response.